# change android.util.Log log text format

Tags: android

I want to change the way the log text is formatted,

Currently when logging with android.util.Log

```
Log.d("tag", "this is the text I added");
```

it comes as

```
<!>com.appname.android.classname 1286<!> this is the text I added
```

I want to output it as

```
[com.appname.android.classname:1286] this is the text I added
```

Any idea how we could do this?

Comment: Is tag equals to `<!>com.appname.android.classname 1286<!>`?

Comment: no that is the file name and line number. it is the default format for logcat. tag appears under its own separate column

Answer (score 0):

The default loggin doesn't work like this. Actually, logs will always be print in a specific format (binary).

Then, what you see, is the result of having another program - usually logcat or the eclipse plugin which probably uses logcat too - that will read that binary log, parse it and present you what you want to see (which fields and with what format).

For example, try typing in the command line

```
 adb logcat
```

And now type

```
 adb logcat -v time
```

**Those were printing exactly the same log, but you saw them with a very different format.**

What you can do is have a program that prints the logs in a different format. I don't think that logcat gives you full control over the format, but some other programs might give you that.

More info:

```
adb logcat --help
```